# SQL CE to Azure sync framework seems to work but is inconsistent

Tags: sql-server-ce, synchronization, azure-sql-database, microsoft-sync-framework

I am new to Sync Framework. This is using version 2.1

My project involves syncing a SQL CE to SQL Azure (soon to be SQL Server 2008)

Right now I am working with a very simple synchronization plan. I want to upload all data in records from Claims and related table Inventory to SQL Azure where the Claims.Status = 'Closed'. That's all I want for now and I've seen it work, but then it won't work. I see no error messages and I don't know what it's doing. I've tried the tracing tool and the results are in Greek and as far as I can tell it doesn't mention anything about the data

Here is an excerpt of the code in a Windows Console App:

```
//For Provisioning...
myScope.Tables.Add(Claims);  
myScope.Tables.Add(Inventory); 

SqlSyncScopeProvisioning sqlAzureProv = new SqlSyncScopeProvisioning(sqlAzureConn, myScope);

sqlAzureProv.Tables["Claims"].AddFilterColumn("Status");
sqlAzureProv.Tables["Claims"].FilterClause = "[side].[Status] = 'Closed'";
sqlAzureProv.Apply();

//For the client...
DbSyncScopeDescription clientSqlCeDesc = SqlSyncDescriptionBuilder.GetDescriptionForScope(myScope.ScopeName, null, "dbo", sqlAzureConn);
SqlCeSyncScopeProvisioning sqlCeProv = new SqlCeSyncScopeProvisioning(sqlCeConn, clientSqlCeDesc);
sqlCeProv.Apply();

//For Syncing:
SqlCeConnection sqlCeConn = new SqlCeConnection(sqlCeConnectionString);
SqlConnection sqlAzureConn = new SqlConnection(sqlazureConnectionString);
SyncOrchestrator orch = new SyncOrchestrator
{
     RemoteProvider = new SqlSyncProvider(scopeName, sqlAzureConn),
     LocalProvider = new SqlCeSyncProvider(scopeName, sqlCeConn),
     Direction = SyncDirectionOrder.Upload
};
Console.WriteLine("ScopeName={0} ", scopeName.ToUpper());
Console.WriteLine("Starting Sync " + DateTime.Now);
ShowStatistics(orch.Synchronize());
```

As for the data on the local and remote dbs, there is one more 'Closed' record on the Local db than there is on the Remote db. I de-provisioned and provisioned to refresh it. Then when I sync, the results shows 38 changes and I don't know what data changes but I do know that the one record that should be updated as 'Closed' is still open.

I've seen this work where I updated two records to be closed on the CE, ran the sync and it syncs. I tried it again with another record and this is what happened. I just want to see consistent results. What am I missing?

Comment: subscribe to the ApplyChangesFailed event of the remote provider and check for sql related errors or conflicts.

Comment: Thanks, FWIW, I do print syncStats.UploadChangesApplied, syncStats.UploadChangesFailed and syncStats.UploadChangesTotal and I have not seen any errors. Is this the same thing? I'm not sure what ApplyChangesFailed is, but I'll figure it out if I need to.

Comment: the ApplyChangesFailed is an event that gets fired if Sync Framework cannot apply a change either due to SQL error or conflicts. just to confirm, the behaviour you're getting is that when you update a row from the client to "Closed" this update is not applied on the server? to find out if the local change is picked up by Sync Framework, subscribe to the ChangesSelected event of the local provider as well. the event argument here has a dataset of changes that were picked up, so you should see whether its detected as a change.

Comment: Thanks.My impression was that synchronization is active, rather than passive. When you say "just to confirm, the behaviour you're getting is that when you update a row from the client to "Closed" this update is not applied on the server?" it makes me think that sync is passive; that I make the update on the client and sync does it's job without my intervention. This would be great and yes, that's what I want to see. Is this the case? I was clueless and now I'm more confused. I am looking into applying the ChangesSelected and how I am to implement it and I'll let you know when I learn something

Comment: One thing I think is strange is that for the Server scope_config data, it has the filter information, but when I look at the scope_config data on the client, all I see are the two tables and no filter information. Does this seem right to you? I'll also edit my question as I changed the code slightly.

Comment: I figured out how to subscribe, when debugging it I found it looped through the Client table twice and the values were as expected.Since they are what we'd expect, how can we know what it's doing on the remote side? I have manually removed the tracking and data tables on the CE db and I've deleted the entire Azure DB. I re-scoped it,synced it and it still isn't uploading anything, no changes. It tells me 24 Changes made, and nothing failed. The only thing I can get out of the ApplyChangesfailed(Remote) is the conflict of LocalInsertRemoteInsert. The data found in ApplyChangesFailed looks fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I apologize to anyone who spent time looking at this post. It was a misunderstanding that I had about how Sync Framework worked. I learned today that static-filters will not propagate changes to existing/tracked records, they will only Insert new records. Sync Framework is far more smooth and much more complicated than I have been giving it credit. I just needed to do more reading and researching.

Special thanks to JuneT, not only for your responses but for the wealth of info that I found on other sites that you have been involved with. Also thanks to anyone else who spent time looking at this post.